# Can't connect to SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, vagrant, sql-server-2012-express

I'm new to SQL Server Express, I'm running on a [vagrant](https://github.com/msabramo/vagrant_sql_server_express) on SQL Server 2012 Express.

I configured user and password and I'm able to connect to the server, but when I add the name of the database I want to connect to it prompts with invalid user/password combination.

I created the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_user1
GO
```

And I have created the user using:

```
CREATE LOGIN [user1] WITH PASSWORD='user1'
GO
CREATE USER [user1] FOR LOGIN [user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

With no errors.

Comment: are you sure to setup the server to be (SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode)?? (right click the instance -> Properties -> Security -> Server Authentication)..

Comment: Also switch to the new database db_user1 before you create the user1 in the db_user1.

Comment: @jonystorm what Sql Surfer said is most likely your problem. You've created the user on master db not on your created db.

Comment: I was working from cmd, I solved it adding the new user to the sysadmin group.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the new user to the sysadmin group.